# Find maximum and minimum value of five consecutive rows by column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the maximum and minimum value of some columns grouped by 5 consecutive values. Example, I want to have maximum by a and minimum by b, of 5 consecutive rows

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  2  5
4  1  1
5  3  6
6  2  8
7  5  2
8  4  6
9  2  7
```

I want to have

```
   a  b
0  3  1
1  5  2
```

(Where 3 is the maximum of 1,2,3,2,1 and 1 is the minumum of 2,3,4,5,1, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Use integer division (`//`) to form the index for grouping by every 5 items, and then use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
out = df.groupby(df.index // 5).agg({'a':'max', 'b':'min'})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   a  b
0  3  1
1  5  2
```